# Label Background Flicker in VB.NET

Tags: label, flicker

So I'm using about 50 different labels on my form, and it flickers any time I do anything(minimize, maximize, run any command on the form) and I need a more efficient way to do this.

I've searched and seen people saying draw the text, but is there any other way? If you suggest drawing the text, what would be a good way to draw 50 different items?

Thanks.

Comment: 50 label should not make the form flicker by itself unless you are running on ancient hardware. can you please post more details? maybe a screenshot

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

2 questions:

1) is the DoubleBuffered property on your form set to true? If not, try that and see if it helps.

2) are you overriding the OnPaint / OnPaintBackground events? If so can you post your code in those?

Comment: The DoubleBuffered property is set to true, and I've tried #2, and nothing seems to work.

Seems like there would be a simple solution to this, but I can't seem to find one.

I'm thinking I may need some hand holding on this, cause I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Hmmm. What else is going on in the form that is UI intensive? Is there a large background image? Are the values in the labels being calculated all at once in some way (if so you could call SuspendLayout() before and ResumeLayout() after)? If you make a copy of the form and start deleting labels, does the flicker go away when you get down to 40/30/20/5?

Comment: The labels are on a small image about 300px x 500px. The values are calculated when you click "Search", but nothing is going on before that. It's just when the form size changes size which kind of bugs me and looks very unprofessional.

Would drawing the text work? I haven't really tried because I haven't found a good way to draw 50 items.

Comment: I don't think you gain anything from drawing the text. As a test, I created a simple VB form with a PictureBox control containing a 500x300 pixel image, and overlaid 50 labels on top. I can resize, move, minimize, etc. the form and get no flickering (and this is without double buffering...). If you get rid of all the labels but one or two does it still flicker?